# the view of UIImagePicker is resized unexpectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I use `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture. I register a notification center for **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification** and **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification**
in *MainViewController*

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(applicationUIDidBecomeActive:)
               name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
             object:nil];

    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(applicationUIWillResignActive:)
               name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
             object:nil];
```

I has *CamController* which is a subclass of `UIImagePickerController`

```
@interface CamController : UIImagePickerController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

When the application did become active, I will display modal view controller according to the code in MainViewContrller.

```
- (void) applicationUIDidBecomeActive: (NSNotification *) aNotification {
    // camController is a instance of CamController
    [camController displayModalWithController:parentViewController animated:NO];
    [camController performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}
```

The below code is in CamController which is a subclass of `UIImagePickerController`

```
- (void) displayModalWithController: (UIViewController*) aController animated: (BOOL) aAnimated {   
    if (aController) 
        [aController presentModalViewController:self animated:aAnimated];       
}

- (void) takePicture {
    [super takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) aPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) aInfo {  
    [self performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:[self mCapturingInterval]];
}
```

When the application will resign active, I dismiss the modal view controller according to the code in MainViewController.

```
- (void) applicationUIWillResignActive: (NSNotification *) aNotification {
    [parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

I test this code on iphone 4 ios 4.2.1, sometimes after I relaunch the application, 
the view of UIImagePicker (the view that's showing the image that we're going to capture) is resized to be smaller, 
not a full screen anymore. I already set the property wantsFullScreenLayout to YES.
When I click home button to bring it to background and then click the application icon to launch application again, the screen may be fullscreen or 
resized. What is the cause of this issue?